Tradingview Charting Library : OnClick event on chart to get price
Base on trading view documents , we can get position of mouse click event , includes :(clientX,clientY,pageX,pageY,screenX,screenY)
but its not useful.
I need the price of clicked point.
https://www.tradingview.com/charting-library-docs/latest/api/interfaces/Charting_Library.SubscribeEventsMap
https://www.tradingview.com/charting-library-docs/latest/api/interfaces/Charting_Library.MouseEventParams
what's the solution?
-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
